# Active Directory Authentication using Email address

Tags: active-directory, authentication

I understand that a user can be authenticated against AD using a username (sAMAcocuntName), but i would like to know if i can use email address as a username to authenticate against AD DS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can't technically login with an email address but the UPN (User Principal Name) was implemented to give users an "email address-like" format to log in with. Each user will have a default UPN from when the domain was created and you can create additional UPN's as desired.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525(v=vs.85).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772007(v=ws.11).aspx